# Installing Qt and MySQL to code and connect with the database

Tags: c++, mysql, qt

I've tried for the past 4 hours to get the MySQL connection with Qt/C++. There are a bunch of posts but they just don't work for me.

I've seen a lot of guides where you just have to move the the .dll files to a certain folder, but they don't work. Some say like place the files inside MinGW/plugins/mysql but I don't even have those folders present.

Then I saw this guide: [Create MySQL driver for Qt5 on Windows](https://www.seppemagiels.com/blog/create-mysql-driver-qt5-windows#mysql_path_note) where you seem to have to build your own driver, and I'm also struggling with this; but, why is this needed? Why other guides and users claim that all you have to do is to copy the files to a specific folder? Is it because a certain version of Qt or MySQL is needed? Which one should I download?

Error I'm getting:

```
QSqlDatabase: QMYSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QSQLITE QODBC QODBC3 QPSQL QPSQL7
```

Actual setup:

- Running Windows 10 64bits
- Qt Creator 4.9.1 - I must have messed up something the last time I re-installed Qt a few mins ago, because now it shows MSVC2017, but I was actually trying with MinGW first...

[image: Qt Creator version]

- MySQL 8.0.18

[image: MySQL version]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set ```QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS``` environment variable to 1 and attach the output debug information to your question.

Comment: Have you enabled the Qt SQL module in QT project settings ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use this : https://github.com/thecodemonkey86/qt_mysql_driver/releases and find your Qt version then download your dll files and then add them to : C:\Qt\Qt version\mingw81_64\bin\ and C:\Qt\Qt version\mingw81_64\plugins\sqldrivers

after this you can run your project by Qt Creator

if you wanna use windeployqt.exe you should be add .dll files to your project directory